# Issue when posting updates/changes to wordress

Tags: theme-development, themes, woocommerce-offtopic

I have WordPress 4.8.1 installed with the OCMX "Department" theme for WooCommerce.

Whenever I update a page or post a new page/slider, I get the following error message:

```
 Warning: Declaration of obox_theme_update::fs_connect($directories = Array) should be compatible with WP_Upgrader::fs_connect($directories = Array, $allow_relaxed_file_ownership = false) in /home/.../wp-content/themes/department/ocmx/includes/update-class.php on line 4

 Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/.../wp-content/themes/department/ocmx/includes/update-class.php:4) in /home/.../wp-admin/post.php on line 197

 Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/.../wp-content/themes/department/ocmx/includes/update-class.php:4) in /home/.../wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1210
```

I have this theme installed on another WP installation on the same server without any issues.  Any ideas what is causing this?  It's currently preventing me from attaching images into my "slider" posts (but text etc will still post successfully).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your theme extends a core WordPress class with its own `fs_connect` function, but doesn't accept the same parameters, which is why it's causing a "should be compatible" error.

This could be caused by WordPress updating it's WP_Upgrader class, in which case your theme will need to update to be compatible. Or, more likely, this website is running PHP with different [error reporting settings](http://php.net/manual/en/migrating5.errorrep.php). This error probably isn't breaking anything, so some settings will hide the error.

Another possibility is running a different PHP version. In PHP 7, for example, the "should be compatible" error no longer requires "strict" error reporting to appear.

Ultimately it's something your theme's developer would need to fix (it should be trivial), so you should report it to them.

The other two errors are just being caused by that first error appearing. Errors that appear at certain points in the page load can interfere with [headers](http://php.net/manual/en/migrating5.errorrep.php), which will cause those errors. Fix the first error and they'll go away.

Comment: Thanks, I downgraded PHP from 7 to 5.6 (in line with the other WP site which uses 5.6) and it's now all fine!

Comment: Cool. Keep in mind that you're just hiding the error. The problem hasn't gone away (not that it will necessarily cause issues), so you should still report to the theme's developer.